# Pool and RMySQL suddenly using the wrong encoding

Tags: r, encoding, pool, rmysql

I've been regularly loading data from my company database. Yesterday I installed R 4.1.3. Since then, the encoding of the data I load using pool is messed up. Not sure what encoding is used, but I'd need UTF-8.

I checked on my colleague's computer, who is still running R 4.1.2, and with the exact same code he doesn't have that issue. Any idea why? And possibly if I can set a global parameter for that?

My session info:

```r
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22000)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Switzerland.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Switzerland.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Switzerland.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                        
[5] LC_TIME=English_Switzerland.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] showtext_0.9-5    showtextdb_3.0    sysfonts_0.8.8    ggnewscale_0.4.6  scales_1.1.1      hrbrthemes_0.8.0  ggthemes_4.2.4    pool_0.1.6       
 [9] highcharter_0.9.4 reshape2_1.4.4    lubridate_1.8.0   zoo_1.8-9         viridis_0.6.2     viridisLite_0.4.0 forcats_0.5.1     stringr_1.4.0    
[17] dplyr_1.0.8       purrr_0.3.4       readr_2.1.2       tidyr_1.2.0       tibble_3.1.6      ggplot2_3.3.5     tidyverse_1.3.1  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] httr_1.4.2        RMySQL_0.10.23    jsonlite_1.8.0    modelr_0.1.8      assertthat_0.2.1  TTR_0.24.3        cellranger_1.1.0  yaml_2.3.5       
 [9] gdtools_0.2.4     Rttf2pt1_1.3.10   pillar_1.7.0      backports_1.4.1   lattice_0.20-45   glue_1.6.2        rlist_0.4.6.2     extrafontdb_1.0  
[17] digest_0.6.29     rvest_1.0.2       colorspace_2.0-3  htmltools_0.5.2   plyr_1.8.6        pkgconfig_2.0.3   broom_0.7.12      haven_2.4.3      
[25] later_1.3.0       tzdb_0.2.0        generics_0.1.2    ellipsis_0.3.2    withr_2.5.0       cli_3.2.0         quantmod_0.4.18   magrittr_2.0.2   
[33] crayon_1.5.0      readxl_1.3.1      evaluate_0.15     fs_1.5.2          fansi_1.0.2       xts_0.12.1        xml2_1.3.3        data.table_1.14.2
[41] tools_4.1.3       hms_1.1.1         lifecycle_1.0.1   munsell_0.5.0     reprex_2.0.1      compiler_4.1.3    systemfonts_1.0.4 rlang_1.0.2      
[49] grid_4.1.3        rstudioapi_0.13   htmlwidgets_1.5.4 igraph_1.2.11     rmarkdown_2.13    gtable_0.3.0      DBI_1.1.2         curl_4.3.2       
[57] R6_2.5.1          gridExtra_2.3     knitr_1.37        fastmap_1.1.0     extrafont_0.17    utf8_1.2.2        stringi_1.7.6     Rcpp_1.0.8.3
```

Comment: what rmysql version are you using?

Comment: @hyman I added my session info to the question. I'm using version 0.10.23, my colleague has 0.10.22